# Проблема с подключением бота на хосте

Tags: python, html, css, telegram-bot, pythonanywhere

Итак начнем, у меня есть код сайта, где пользователь создает свой пост и этот пост сохраняется в базе данных, теперь я хочу, чтобы вместе с этим пришло сообщение моему tg боту, весь код уже написан на моей машине, все работает, но как только дело доходит до публикации, на хосте все не работает, все, что я смог выяснить, это то, что если вырезать часть кода, где работает tg бот, все начинает работать.

это мой главный код

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, session, request, render_template
from db_scripts import *
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

bot_token = 'Token_Bot'

with open('users.txt', 'r') as file:
    chat_ids = [line.strip() for line in file]

def send_notification(category_name):
    message = f"Был добавлен новый пост в категории: {category_name}"
    bot_api_url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/sendMessage'

    for chat_id in chat_ids:
        payload = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': message}
        response = requests.post(bot_api_url, data=payload)


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/post/category/<category_name>',methods=['POST','GET'])
def postCategory(category_name):
    user = getUser()
    category_id = getIdByCategory(category_name)
    
    if request.method == 'GET':
        posts = getPostByCategory(category_id)
        post_id = getPostID(category_id)
        for id_post in post_id:
            num = int(id_post[0])
            tags = getPostTag(num)
            print(tags)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        posts = getPostByCategory(category_id)
        post_id = getPostID(category_id)
        for id_post in post_id:
            num = int(id_post[0])
            tags = getPostTag(num)
            print(tags)
        
        filename = None
        if request.files['formImage'].filename != '':
            image = request.files['formImage']
            image.save(f"{PATH_UPLOADS}{image.filename}")
            filename = image.filename

        addPost(category_id, request.form['formText'],request.form['formTitle'],filename, request.form['formTag'])
        posts = getPostByCategory(category_id)

        send_notification(category_name)

    return render_template('post_category.html',category_name=category_name, user=user,posts=posts)

@app.route('/post/delete/<post_id>/<category_name>')
def deletePost(post_id, category_name):
    delPost(post_id)
    return redirect(f'/post/category/{category_name}')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    user = getUser()
    return render_template('about.html',user=user,image1=getImage()[0],image2=getImage()[1],image3=getImage()[2],image4=getImage()[3])

@app.route('/auth',methods=['POST','GET'])
def auth_user():
    return render_template('auth.html')

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Shirase8888'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Подозреваю что PythonAnywhere не разрешает вам подключится к `api.telegram.org`, можете попытаться обратиться к администраторам ресурса и ссылкой на публичный API и хостом (`api.telegram.org`) с просьбой его разблокировать.

Comment: а есть ли способ на прямую написать админам PythonAnywhere  для просьбы разблокировки api.telegram.org?